# Applying style to parent element in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, episerver

I have a requirement to add a class to a p-tag if it has an a-tag child, like this:

```
<p class="read-more-link">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</p>
```

I've tried the following without success (this is C# in EPiServer):

```
new {title="Read more link", selector="p", classes="read-more-link" } // this allows user to add class to any p
new {title="Read more link", selector="p > a", classes="read-more-link" } // this adds class to a tag
new {title="Read more link", selector="p > a", classes="read-more-link", wrapper="true" } // this does nothing
new {title="Read more link", selector="p > a", block="p", classes="read-more-link", wrapper="true" } // this does nothing
new {title="Read more link", selector="a", block="p", classes="read-more-link", wrapper="true" } // this does nothing
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Here's a fiddle that shows the problem: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/0xhaab/4

Comment: Does `new { title="Read more link", block="p", classes="read-more-link", wrapper="true" }` work, without `selector`?

Comment: Yes it does, but that means that you can add the class to any p-tag, not only those that have a child a-tag and that should not be allowed

Comment: A wrapper will be added around the selected element. In other words, the wrapper means you can add a `<p>` tag with the specified CSS classes _around_ any element selected in the editor. AFAIK there is no way to specify that a wrapper should only be available to wrap specific elements.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a wrapper, see https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-formatting/#wrapper

Comment: I've tried that, see my edit in the original question, but can't get it to work